# Getting error while reading from a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

Am getting an error while trying to read from a text file in javascript .

This is the code

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        Dwell time for workers

    </head>
    <script src = "https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/comments/require.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="workers_dwell_time_final1.json"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

    //var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
    //console.log(mydata[0].name);
    //console.log(mydata[0].time);
    //  <script src = "https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js" > /script>
    const fs = require('fs') 

    // Reading data in utf-8 format 
    // which is a type of character set. 
    // Instead of 'utf-8' it can be  
    // other character set also like 'ascii' 
    fs.readFile('myfile.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => { 
        if (err) throw err; 

    // Converting Raw Buffer to text 
    // data using tostring function. 
    console.log(data); 
}) 



    </script>


<body>
    <h1> worker time : </h1>

</body>


</html>
```

This is the error

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (require.js:1436)
    at requirejs (require.js:1797)
    at Dashboard.html:18
```

**What do i do to remove the error** . If someone has the appropriate require.js file please do share it

Comment: Unless you’re using Electron or the like this doesn’t do what you expect. `fs` is a node module. It cannot be used on the web and a web browser never ever will allow you to read local files by path (only files a user selects via a file input).

Comment: I agree with @idmean, you cannot messing up with files from browser.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is loading a module which is not bundled most probably with the app. And Also I do not think you can read that like this. Not in a webpage (compared to nodejs). You will need to serve that file from a server from (it's public folder, see: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp ).